# Best way to make a temporary account to share with co-workers?

Tags: support, jobs, user-accounts, shared-accounts

I would like to allow my co-workers to share my account for a temporary amount of time (3 weeks).

I would like to do this so that they have access to and visibility into my Stack Overflow Careers recruiting activity.

If I could isolate that login to Stack Overflow Careers only, that would be ideal, but it is not necessary.

I see that I can go to logins > add login, but I don't see a way to add an arbitrary username and password.

What is the best way to temporarily share account access with others?
(And, is this allowed for SO Careers purposes?)

Comment: Creating a new OpenID and associating it with your account would be the way to go, but only if you trust your co-workers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a login will work for adding an openID. If you'd like to add another email/password login to your account, create a separate account with those credentials and email a merge request to careers at stackoverflow dot com. This will give anyone logging in with those credential access to your full account, including your Careers profile (should you have one).

Comment: I did this (new OpenID from an independent provider) without the merge request, I didn't see the value in that (unless I can request an unmerge later). Anyway, it's worked out fine. Thanks!