# Is possible to add accounts in a "company account"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, linked-accounts, merged-questions, company

We are 3 developers at the moment and we are all active on Stack Overflow.

We were wondering if it would be possible to create a "company account" where we add all our personal accounts. It would be nice to show a total combined rating for our Q&A activity using a company profile.

Is this possible? Or could it be of interest for a future update of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Like a group similar to a reputation league or truly a shared account?

Comment: I get the feeling that something like this would be easier to accomplish though [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com).  Not sure how I feel about it being a generic option; I feel that it could be abused a lot.

Comment: A shared account, a company account with inside 3 different personal account.

Comment: What would the behavior of this account be? Should it always display your individual activity as the company? Or should the company account only be clarified when visiting your personal profiles? It also seems to slowly approach social grouping, so this should certainly be limited if supported at all.

Comment: Just an aggregator of company users account, that show all the Q / A of the users and activities.

Comment: Aggregating is possible on OpenHub and is useful to have a company's profile, especially for those providing service, e.g. https://www.openhub.net/orgs/Savoir-faireLinux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the view on accounts shared by multiple users on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82509/what-is-the-view-on-accounts-shared-by-multiple-users-on-stack-overflow) Especially the answer by Shog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to make a temporary account to share with co-workers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130233/282094),   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341857/282094, and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309276/update-the-terms-of-service-to-reflect-the-established-community-consensus-on-sh#comment1008003_309280 suggest the opposite of the other duplicate.