# When seeing account sharing, what should I do? Especially when the result is a low-quality post

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, low-quality-posts, shared-accounts

There was a formally bad, newbie-looking question (formatting, question part in comment, stuff like that) by a 2K+ user. I commented wondering about this, and it came up that the question was in fact asked by a friend.

I did the usual "bad question" things, and in comments suggested he should educate this friend on how to ask questions at SO in future, and pointed out that creating an account is free and you can ask a question even without an account, and suggested he should edit the question to meet SO standards.

My understanding is that account sharing isn't necessarily a problem at SO, so should I do something more, such as flag the question for moderator attention?

In addition to should I flag or not, I'd like clarification about different aspects of the whole thing: account sharing in general ([seems to be mostly OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82509/what-is-the-view-on-accounts-shared-by-multiple-users-on-stack-overflow)?), and account sharing of high-rep accounts (and what is "high-rep" for this purpose), and a shared high-rep account producing low-quality posts.

Comment: Found the question. You seem to be handling it pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at questions and answers on their own tells you what to do. If it is a bad questions or answer, downvote, flag, vote to close and comment as appropriate. Treat posts based on what they are, not based on who posted them.

Now if such a bad post came out of a high-rep account with mostly or only otherwise good contributions, then you should comment and ask what's going. Having an account shared is only problematic if one of the participants is using it to avoid or circumvent a question ban. Unfortunately there's not much we can do in such a case, as proofing such a thing is complicated and even if we'd know, we can't simply ban a high-rep user with good contributions. The best way would be what you already did, comment and suggest that the other user of the account should create their own, linking to the help center and other material clearly outlining this.

If it ever happens and you figure out or somebody tells you that the account has been overtaken or even been bought by the new user (hey, people sell all kind of weird stuff on eBay), flag for moderator attention and explain the manner. I do not know of any policy in this regards, but creating accounts, pushing them to a certain rep and then giving or selling them (so that the new user "has a good standing with the community to start with") does not sound like something we want.

Answer (score 1):

I see two parts in here.

First one: is it *valid* (aka: allowed) to share an account. The [ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) in 2020 say:

> To access some of the public Network features you will need to register for an account as an individual and consent to these Public Network Terms

So you can't register as "group".

> ... control the use and sharing of your account information

Could be read as: sharing your account information is allowed.

But in the end: it is a grey area.

So "sharing" alone, without doing something that is otherwise considered inappropriate, is still (or: even more) okay in 2020. Personally, I dislike that stance (for me a user is that: a user, **one** specific human being). But I really don't see any solid ground to "condemn" account sharing, while otherwise following all the rules.

Thus: no need to sanction "sharing" by itself. Instead, look at the quality of postings, and act accordingly.

---

<sub>Beyond that, there might even be neat use cases for account sharing, such as a single "open source product X support" user which is used by multiple people doing "support" for X. But it seems that this usage pattern was discussed and dismissed as "not allowed.</sub>

Comment: The last paragraph has been discussed bedore, and the outcome was that it is not allowed. Mainly because the notfication system isn't designed to cope with this

Comment: @Luuklag Anyway, I trust your word, so I reworded that part of the answer. That wasnt my key point anyway.

Comment: I believe it was a comment from Shog? somewhere, but unable to find it right now.